# Storybook: How to have a "select" control with options but also free text?

Tags: storybook

In storybook (React), I have set-up the following control that correctly displays `iconClass` as a select. I want it to provide those three "most used" options, but also give the user the ability to input a custom value. How to get this hybrid select / input text control? Thanks

```json
  argTypes: {
    iconClass: {
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: [
          'fa-arrows-alt-v',
          'fa-arrows-alt-h',
          'fa-link',
        ]
      },
    }
  }
```